# Adding element to array and using that array again

Tags: java, arrays, loops, passwords

For a class I have to create a program that asks a user for a password, and if they enter one that isn't already listed, add it to the list and allow them to enter it again and be correct. I tried writing a method to duplicate the array and add the new password but it doesn't work. Can someone tell me where I went wrong here? Oh and I have to use an array not an arraylist :(

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String pin;

    do {
        System.out.print("Please enter the password: ");
        pin = console.nextLine();
        checkPassword(pin);
    } while (!checkPassword(pin));



}

public static boolean checkPassword (String pin) {
    String[] passwords = {"9999", "coastal", "1"};

    if (Arrays.stream(passwords).anyMatch(pin::equals)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        int count = 0;
        String[] newWord = new String[passwords.length + 1];
        for(int i=0; i < passwords.length; i++){
             newWord[i]= passwords[i];
             count++;
        }
        newWord[count] = pin;

        passwords = newWord;
        System.out.print("Password was not in array. It has now been added. Try logging in again.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first mistake that you are using local variable for passwords, so it always initialized when you are calling method.

Second that you are checking password twice: first check and then loop condition check.

So recommend you to use one filed instead of local variable for passwords, and perform only one check, then the program will work correctly.

Updated code:

```
public class Test {
    private static String[] passwords = {"9999", "coastal", "1"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        String pin;

        boolean valid = false;
        do {
            System.out.print("Please enter the password: ");
            pin = console.nextLine();
            valid = checkPassword(pin);
        } while (!valid);


    }

    public static boolean checkPassword(String pin) {
        if (Arrays.stream(passwords).anyMatch(pin::equals)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            int count = 0;
            String[] newWord = new String[passwords.length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < passwords.length; i++) {
                newWord[i] = passwords[i];
                count++;
            }
            newWord[count] = pin;

            passwords = newWord;
            System.out.print("Password was not in array. It has now been added. Try logging in again.");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood of your question, you have a list of passwords and what you're trying to do is ask the user to insert a password and then re-insert it in order to verify if the re-inserted password matches the first one.

In order to do that you have to promp the user for it's input and add the received password to the password lists. After that prompt the user again for the same password and check if this password exists in the password list. If the insertion is correct that password should be there since the user added it the first time.

This implementation that you're doing is not the best though. Try using dictionaries in order to associate a password to a user name. You can also request 2 inputs and compare them in order to verify if they are the same and THEN add the password to the dictionary.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is related to *variable scopes*. Whenever the current method reaches the end of execution, its variables will go out of scope and be eligble for garbage collection. You can say that `passwords` is a local variable.

Now, tough you do save an updated version of the array in the method, it will be discarded and not visible to subsequent calls.

```
public static boolean checkPassword (String pin) {
    String[] passwords = {"9999", "coastal", "1"};
    ...
} // here, passwords goes out of scope
```

To fix your error, you either have to store it globally or add it as a method parameter.

```
// global
private static String[] passwords = {"9999", "coastal", "1"};

// method parameter
public static boolean checkPassword (String pin, String[] passwords) {
    ...
}
```